Unable to use Android Glance beta02
When I update Glance library to the latest version beta02
implementation(dependencyNotation = "androidx.glance:glance-appwidget:1.1.0-beta02")

I have a compilation error:
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':Tisseo:mergeExtDexDev'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':Tisseo:devRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform glance-appwidget-1.1.0-beta02.aar (androidx.glance:glance-appwidget:1.1.0-beta02) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, dexing-component-attributes=ComponentSpecificParameters(minSdkVersion=26, debuggable=true, enableCoreLibraryDesugaring=true, enableGlobalSynthetics=true, enableApiModeling=false, dependenciesClassesAreInstrumented=false, asmTransformComponent=null, useJacocoTransformInstrumentation=false, enableDesugaring=true, needsClasspath=false, useFullClasspath=false, componentIfUsingFullClasspath=null), org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingNoClasspathTransform: /Users/kevinabrioux/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/0a444880f32c1d7efbe6ef158cef70ee/transformed/jetified-glance-appwidget-1.1.0-beta02-runtime.jar.
         > Error while dexing.

How can I fix this ?

Did you find the fix for this issue?

@Amaan I have used the stable version 1.1.0: implementation("androidx.glance:glance-appwidget:1.1.0") No problems since
